# PowerBuilder Insert a record to a SQL table if it is not available messagebox if not

Tags: validation, powerbuilder, datastore, sql-insert

I am fairly new to PowerBuilder Classic 12.
I need a sample code to check whether a record is available and if not insert from a textbox.
I would probably need a DataStore since someone suggested a preference to SQL statements.
Thanks.

Comment: Beware not to use the datastore as a [golden hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). When a single sql stqtement looks useful, use a simple sql statement.

Comment: I did with an Sql statement but the select statement was bypassed and the insert one executed. Help with the SQL statements

Comment: I am not sure to understand correctly. Can you show some code?

Comment: @Seki: In my experience, embedded SQL is often a golden _sledgehammer_.

Comment: @Seki I'd disagree in a lot of cases. A DataWindow/DataStore will outperform most embedded SQL, because the DW object stores the DESCRIBE done at design time, whereas embedded SQL has to do it at run time. (Let's skip advantages like centralized error handling, SQL injection protection, etc... I've only 272 characters left!!) I'd use embedded SQL to fill in the DW's weakness that it is designed to INSERT/UPDATE a single row. If you can handle multiple row manipulation with a single DML statement, that (IMHO) is the time to use embedded SQL.

Comment: @RGI am using sql server 2008 and powerbuilder classic 12.5.

Comment: You said: "I did with an Sql statement but the select statement was bypassed and the insert one executed". Are you talking about embedded SQL? Did you do a select into using host variables, or a cursor? If you used a cursor remember you need to define it and then fetch into to get values.  I agree with Hugh, that in many cases using datawindow/dataobject is usually the better way to go. It seems that many problem areas of a PB program end up being embedded SQL for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

### I'm not sure if this is answering your Q, but here you go:

string ls_CheckRecord
string ls_InsertRecord

SELECT record2Check
INTO :ls_Check
FROM myTable
WHERE conditionsMet;

If ( SQLCA.SQLCode <> 0 ) Then
    Messagebox("SQL Error",SQLCA.SQLErrText)
    Return
End if

If (NOT IsNull(ls_Check) ) Then
   ls_InsertRecord = sle_ToInsert.Text

INSERT myTable
   (myColumn)
   VALUES
   (:ls_InsertRecord) ;

If ( SQLCA.SQLCode <> 0 ) Then
    Messagebox("SQL Error",SQLCA.SQLErrText)
    Return
   End if
End if